# Apache DBUtils QueryRunner returning ids from wrong column in insert

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbutils

I am using Apache DBUtils

```
Long rowId = queryRunner.insert(sql, new ScalarHandler<Long>(), params);
```

My table schema is

```
CREATE TABLE abc
(
    userid bigint,
    api_key text,
    key_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('api_keys_key_id_seq'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT api_keys_pkey PRIMARY KEY (key_id),
    CONSTRAINT userid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (userid)
    REFERENCES public.users (userid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Problem is `rowId` is coming from `userid` column where as primary key of table is `key_id` and i want the returning id of insert query to be from `key_id` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which i followed was to create table again with `key_id` as first column. In this way `key_id` was returned in response to insert query. There may be an option to configure this but i was unable to find.

I know creating a table again for this is not good approach but anyone found answer please do share.